# Gridview not updating on pageload

Tags: c#, gridview, ado.net

I have a gridview does not update on pageload. If you insert a value into the table, the page posts back and the gridview remains the same. All tho the record is inserted into the database. I'm fairly new to ADO.NET, any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class Equip_DB : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NIC"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand showAll = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Equiptment", con);

            SqlDataReader reads = showAll.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataSource = reads;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NIC"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        //INSERT INTO Equiptment VALUES ('2', 'Hammers', '24')
        string query = "INSERT INTO Equiptment VALUES ('"+
            equipAmount.Text +"', '"+
            equipType.Text + "', '" +
            DropDownList1.SelectedValue +"')";
        AddContract.Visible = true;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not binding gridview with updated content.

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NIC"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        //INSERT INTO Equiptment VALUES ('2', 'Hammers', '24')
        string query = "INSERT INTO Equiptment VALUES ('"+
            equipAmount.Text +"', '"+
            equipType.Text + "', '" +
            DropDownList1.SelectedValue +"')";
        AddContract.Visible = true;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
//GRID LOAD CODE GOES HERE


        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand showAll = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Equiptment", con);

            SqlDataReader reads = showAll.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataSource = reads;
            GridView1.DataBind();
}

///////////////////////

        }
        catch {
            con.Close();
        }
    }  


        }
```